# iOS 12 beta 4 CoreLocation from background launch

Tags: core-location, ios12

My app tracks users' travel (with their knowledge and consent, and with appropriate permissions set). A significant location change event starts the app, and then the app starts updating locations.

This works great for iOS 10 and 11, but it isn't working for the iOS 12 betas (tested beta 3 and 4) - the app is getting started, but it is either not getting location updates, or it is not staying active in the background.

I filed a bug report with Apple, and they called my bug report a dupe of an existing bug that's open, but I couldn't see details on the existing bug.

Does anyone have any more information on this? I scoured release notes and developer event presentations, but I didn't find any mention of something Apple purposefully changed that might cause this.

What I'd really like to know is if there's an intended behavior change that I need to support before the final iOS 12 release. Even better, if there's some workaround that will get this working in the beta versions, that would let me sleep at night...

Comment: Did you find anything regarding this?

Comment: No, I haven't found anything. It seems to be working better since beta 5 or 6, but I'm not sure if Apple fixed it.

Comment: I have observed the same. Lets see what the public release will do. But I am pretty sure, it will mess up similar to any other iOS upgrade in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in iOS 12 beta 5 or 6 - upgraded iOS and it started working without other changes.